# Download Large File Efficiently

Tags: c#, http

I have written following method to download file and save in c# with `.net framework 4.7.2` is being used.

```cs
public static bool DownloadFiles(Uri url, string filePath)
{
    try
    {
        
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            using (var stream = client.GetStreamAsync(url))
            {
                using (var fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
                {
                    stream.Result.CopyTo(fs);
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        
        return false;
    }
}
```

Is above code is efficient for large file, I tried to do some performance analysis but haven't drawn some definite conclusion. I am new to C# as it is not my primary tech stack, Any suggestion will be hugely helpful.

Comment: you should think about doing the download asynchron

Comment: @nbk are you talking about this - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadfileasync?view=net-7.0

Comment: yes, there are more possibility but that is ok instead of waiting on the file you need to invest a littele in asynchronous communication, you then can download in the background

Comment: How should *we know if the aboce fits your needs? You need to measure yourself, and check if you have difficulties with that code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function should be async. `HttpClient` should be NOT disposed [Call a Web API From a .NET Client (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client):

```cs
public static class HttpUtils
{
    static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    public static async Task<bool> DownloadFilesAsync(Uri url, string filePath)
    {
        try
        {

            using (var stream = await client.GetStreamAsync(url))
            {
                using (var fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
                {
                    await stream.CopyToAsync(fs);
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response, does this stream `client.GetStreamAsync(url)` fetch in chunks, can this cause memory issue?

Comment: Yes it copies by chunks.

Comment: `CopyToAsync` also have overload if you want to configure buffer size.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few improvements and considerations that can be made for better performance.

- `GetStreamAsync` is an asynchronous method that returns a `Task<Stream>`.
  You should use `await` it to get the actual stream.
- For large files, using `CopyTo` might consume a lot of memory.
  Consider using a buffer to read chunks of data from the source stream
  and write them to the destination stream.

```
public static async Task<bool> DownloadFiles(Uri url, string filePath)
{
    try
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            using (Stream stream = await client.GetStreamAsync(url))
            {
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
                {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192]; // 8KB buffer (can adjust size)
                    int bytesRead;
                    while ((bytesRead = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                    {
                        await fs.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Handle exceptions appropriately (log, notify, etc.)
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: CopyTo uses a buffer, you can even specify the size.